# Will WTSQuerySessionInformation work for totally remote RDP servers?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, c++11, remote-desktop

The MSDN function is alled WTSQuerySessionInformation. I did some testings as far as my entry level coding skills allows me, but I must be missing something.

Basically, I need to check several times a day if and who is logged on into a RDP server, by checking a specific session id. 
In my imagination and pseudo-code, i imagined it will go something like supply the server, the session id, and get the username.

Skipping the high tech details and issues with WTS_INFO_CLASS and what not, my top concern is if WTSQuerySession is even designed to work on a totally remote server? The servers in question are not on my network and either one of them is linked to any other.

Comment: Forgot to mention, if someone will suggest using WTSEnumerateSessions beforehand, that thing is out of the question, and RPC calls will be denied by the RDP servers. So any suggestion involving RPC calls won't be of much help to me

Comment: What makes you think that WTSQuerySessionInformation doesn't use RPC?  It uses the same sort of server handle as WTSEnumerateSessions, so if that doesn't work, WTSQuerySessionInformation is unlikely to.

Comment: Harry, thanks for taking your time to reply. Ok, I'm starting to get the idea. So is there any alternative to what I am trying to accomplish ? Is it worth asking another question?

Comment: Typically you would install a system service on the RDP servers to respond to your queries.  That could use a named pipe, if that functionality is available, or it could listen on a TCP port - though in the latter case you have to take care of authenticating the request yourself.